# Creating patch using P4Eclipse plugin fails with "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perforce

I searched and saw a couple of semi-relevant posts but none specifically for the P4Eclipse plugin in OS X. I have been able to create a patch from the command line, but I would like to get the plugin working since it will make my life much easier. Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to create a patch which will be used for a pre-commit code review. To do so I am right-clicking my project in the Package Explorer, then navigating through "Team > Create Patch" to open the Create Patch Wizard. I select an export location by providing a filesystem path, then select the files I'd like to include in my patch, then provide the path to the p4 executable. I click "Finish" and a "Patch failed" dialog comes up with multiple exceptions which are all the same and say "Patch Exception: Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset."

[This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Perforce+password+%28P4PASSWD%29+invalid+or+unset+on+JIRA+Fisheye+plugin) is the most helpful link I've found but I'm not sure exactly what it's saying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same issue, it used to work before for me, not sure why, but not anymore..

Comment: Sounds like a bug. I'd suggest contacting support.

Comment: Same issue.  Perhaps the Perforce Eclipse plugin has cached an old perforce password, so it errors when you give the current one ...

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and by setting the command to point to a custom batch file and recording what was being passed to the command, I figured out what was happening. The problem is that the Eclipse plugin is passing the password to p4 command using the -P parameter and if perforce is set to disallow passwords in this way, you will see the "Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset." error. If you login first using:
   p4 login
it will create a ticket and you don't need to specify the password.

My fix was to create a simple batch file which simply passes on all parameters apart from -P and the password and select this in the Eclipse patch dialog instead of p4.exe:

p4-pw.cmd:

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@SHIFT /7
@SHIFT /7
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Perforce\p4.exe" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue while trying to commit a new file but then I added P4PASSWD in system variables(Windows) with my password as the value. Restarted eclipse and it solved my problem

Comment: Does this mean you have to store you password in plain text in an environment variable.  That's a huge security risk.